# Unexpected ';' while compiling ejs file that does not have ';' at all

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, ejs

I am getting this error in this file for a while now, and I can't understand the reason.
I don't even have a semi-colon in this file

```
<section class="content">
        <% switch(page){ %>
          <% case : "userpage" %>
          <div><%- include("all_users")  %></div>
          <% break %>
          <% case : "postpage" %>
          <div><%- include("all_posts")  %></div>
          <% break %>
          <% default : %>
          <div><%- include("card") %></div>
        <% } %>
</section>
```

When `page = "dashboard"` it is going to include `card.ejs` file that too does not even have semi-colon.
What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Its answered here https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that, the statement :

```
<% switch(page){ %>
```

is compiled as a seperate statement, and a `;` is appended after it. Put it in the same `bracket` (<%) as the first case statement and it should work:

```
  <% switch(page){
          case : "userpage" %>
          <div><%- include("all_users")  %></div>
          <% break;
          case : "postpage" %>
          <div><%- include("all_posts")  %></div>
          <% break;
          default : %>
          <div><%- include("card") %></div>
        <% } %>
```